# Alternatives to XDialog

Tags: scripting

Are there any alternatives to XDialog?

Ideally something that would support both X server and terminal interface.

Comment: Actually writing a GTK+2 program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Zenity](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity)** - GTK-based, neat, relatively lightweight (if you already have GTK pulled in by other programs, that is).